# Is there any condition under which $\nabla\cdot F=0$ implies $F=0$?

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator, electromagnetism

On a physics course it was stated that
$$
\nabla\cdot\vec{D}=\rho_f=\nabla\cdot(\varepsilon_0\vec{E})
$$
and then *it follows* that
$$
\vec{D}=\varepsilon_0\vec{E}
$$
I know this is not generally true, but was wondering if there were some conditions for it to be so.

EDIT: It turned out I was missing some details on the argument, and the latter isn't a true implication.
I'm still interested in the title's question though, and would like to hear about it.

Comment: This argument just isn't right. You might want to double check that the argument says what you say it says. Does the course *really* infer $F=G$ from $\text{div}(F)=\text{div}(G)$?

Comment: You're right, I was missing some other details that led to that equation, and that of the divergences was just complementary. The question stills stands though, but for the general case.

Comment: The title asks about a vector field with zero divergence.  If the divergence is zero everywhere we call it [solenoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field).  However this is a long way from being a zero vector field or even a constant vector field.  The condition of zero divergence ("divergence free") arises in connection with a fluid that is *incompressible* (and thus the net flow across any bounding surface is zero).  That may help you grasp a three dimensional interpretation of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

What really follows is that the vector field $\vec{D} - \varepsilon_0 \vec{E}$ is **solenoidal**, i.e. its divergence is $0$.  For example, the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ always has this property.